# Подружить 3D эффект и Nivo слайдер

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго всем здравия
Хочу подружить Nivo-слайдер [пример тут](http://icar-soft.ru/nivo_code.html) и
3D эффект [пример тут](http://icar-soft.ru/Veneris/3D_Veneris.html).
Но что-то при подключении второго, первый отрубается, я так понимаю переменные из JQuery.js и jquery***_***nivo***_***slider_pack.js перекрывают друг друга, я верно предполагаю?
И как их можно "подружить" или только переписывать весь JQuery.js (переписывать переменные)?
———
**P.S.** может быть в JS есть, что-то типа переменных в контейнере

Comment: Подключите [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) один раз, а не отдельно для слайдера и эффекта. Мне кажется Вы не совсем понимаете что это за библиотека.

Comment: Именно, что я её и подключаю один раз.
пример кода: http://jsfiddle.net/J4btj/1/

Comment: Ни у кого подобного опыта что ли не было?  
Подключения NivoSlider'a и такого вот 3D.  
А может заменить слайдер на другой движок? Не Nivo, а другой-какой-нибудь попробовать?

Comment: никому не хочется иметь опыт ковыряния в вашем коде который непонятно работает или нет. для начала **подключите библиотеки**